# VBA DOM ParentNode SelectSingleNode

Tags: xml, vba, dom, xpath, xml-parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
<book id="Adventure">
   <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
   <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
   <price>44.95</price>
</book>
<book id="Adventure">
   <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
   <title>Midnight Rain</title>
   <price>5.95</price>
</book>
<book id="Adventure">
   <author>Boal, John</author>
   <title>Mist</title>
   <price>15.95</price>
</book>
<book id="Mystery">
   <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
   <title>Some Mystery Book</title>
   <price>9.95</price>
</book>
</catalog>
```

My program searches for all items by a specific author ("Ralls, Kim"), and at the same time gathers the BookType ("book id") and throws the values into an array.

The issue now though is that the book id's aren't always going to be the same. So since I've already established what the parent node is, I want to pull out the BookTitle - this way I don't have to put a variable in the XPATH that is already stored in an array (that sounds like a nightmare to me).

```
Sub mySub()

Dim XMLFile As Variant
Dim Author As Variant
Dim athr As String, BookType As String, Title As String
Dim AuthorArray() As String, BookTypeArray() As String, TitleArray() As  String
Dim i As Long, x As Long, j As Long

Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
Dim n As IXMLDOMNode
Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set XMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
XMLFile.Load ("C:\Books.xml")


x = 1
j = 0

Set Author = XMLFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/book/author/text()")
For i = 0 To (Author.Length - 1)
    ReDim Preserve AuthorArray(0 To i)
    ReDim Preserve BookTypeArray(0 To i)
    ReDim Preserve TitleArray(0 To i)
    athr = Author(i).NodeValue
    BookType = Author(i).ParentNode.ParentNode.getAttribute("id")
    Title = Author(i).ParentNode.SelectSingleNode("title")

    If athr = "Ralls, Kim" Then

        AuthorArray(j) = athr
        BookTypeArray(j) = BookType
        TitleArray(j) = Title

        j = j + 1
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next



Range("A3:A" & UBound(AuthorArray) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(AuthorArray)
Range("B3:B" & UBound(BookTypeArray) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(BookTypeArray)
Range("C3:C" & UBound(BookTypeArray) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(TitleArray)


End Sub
```

I keep getting an object error on this line of code and I don't understand why:

```
Title = Author(i).ParentNode.SelectSingleNode("title")
```

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not familiar with VBA, but most likely you are getting an error because this line

```
Set Author = XMLFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/book/author/text()")
```

sets an `Author` variable (?) to a *string* value, `text()` means the concatenation of all text nodes that are immediate children of the context element. Strings are very different from elements, they do not have attributes, or child elements.

They *do* have a parent node, but

```
BookType = Author(i).ParentNode.getAttribute("id")
```

will try to retrieve the `id` attribute of the parent of such a text node, which is an `author` element - but `author` elements do not have an `id` attribute.

Change

```
Set Author = XMLFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/book/author/text()")
```

to

```
Set Author = XMLFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/book/author")
```

and let me know if that helps.

---

**EDIT**: I think I found a working solution, how about the following. However, I am absolutely unfamiliar with VBA - I'm sure this is not a very elegant solution and could be improved a lot.

```
Sub mySub()

Dim XMLFile As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim Author As Variant
Dim athr As String, BookType As String, Title As String
Dim AuthorArray() As String, BookTypeArray() As String, TitleArray() As String
Dim i As Long, x As Long, j As Long

Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
Dim n As IXMLDOMNode
Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set XMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
XMLFile.Load ("vba.xml")


x = 1
j = 0

Set Author = XMLFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/book/author")
For i = 0 To (Author.Length - 1)
    ReDim Preserve AuthorArray(0 To i)
    ReDim Preserve BookTypeArray(0 To i)
    ReDim Preserve TitleArray(0 To i)
    athr = Author(i).Text
    BookType = Author(i).ParentNode.getAttribute("id")
    Title = Author(i).ParentNode.getElementsByTagName("title").Item(0).nodeTypedValue

    If athr = "Ralls, Kim" Then

        AuthorArray(j) = athr
        BookTypeArray(j) = BookType
        TitleArray(j) = Title

        j = j + 1
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next



Range("A3:A" & UBound(AuthorArray) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(AuthorArray)
Range("B3:B" & UBound(BookTypeArray) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(BookTypeArray)
Range("C3:C" & UBound(BookTypeArray) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(TitleArray)


End Sub
```

**Result**

```
Ralls, Kim  Adventure   Midnight Rain
Ralls, Kim  Mystery     Some Mystery Book
```

---

**2nd EDIT**

> can you please explain what Item(0) is doing in this line `Title = Author(i).ParentNode.getElementsByTagName("title").Item(0).nodeTypedValue`?

`getElementsByTagName()` returns a *collection* of elements, even if there is one one result - it would end up in a collection with just one item. `Item(0)` selects the first element in this collection.

Then, [`nodeTypedValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762308%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns the value of an object, depending on its data type. By the way, the `NodeValue` property [only works on attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213915%28v=office.11%29.aspx) - that's why your code returned an error.

> Also, is there ever a need for using /text() within the XPath to the node (it doesn't seem to affect numbers or anything either)?

(Finally something I'm comfortable with! I think you would profit from an introduction or tutorial to XPath.)

`text()` *is* a highly overused construct, but yes, there are uses for it. Think about it that way: When XML is read into memory, a tree-like representation is constructed. In this representation, all kinds of objects are nodes; elements are nodes, attributes are nodes - and text content is a node.

Now, an XPath expression like

```
/catalog/book/author
```

selects an *element node* (or, possibly, a set of element nodes). In your case, it is an element node that has a text node as its child. Extending the path expression to

```
/catalog/book/author/text()
```

selects *only* the child text nodes of `author` elements. It's important to understand that an element and its text content are not the same.

Comment: Thanks for your response Mathias :) Unfortunately in VBA, `text()` is required because it essentially says 'hey get the text that's after /author'. To be specific, the error I get is **Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set**. When I remove that line of code, my program works. I think it has something to do with the syntax, because if I set it to something like `Title = Author(i).ParentNode.ParentNode.getAttribute("id")` it works.

Comment: @NRH That's what I am trying to explain. Only the grandparent node of this text node really has an `id` attribute.

Comment: @NRH Also, why would `text()` be required in VBA?

Comment: Hi Mathias - that's what I've learned from my readings online; I might be wrong though because I'm still really new to this. I did try your recommendation, it gives a **Run-time error '94' Invalid use of Null** on the line `athr = Author(i).NodeValue`

Comment: What if we use something like NextSibling/PreviousSibling? Do you think that can work in a loop if there were several more books too?

Comment: @NRH No, iterating through a set of wanted nodes with searching for next siblings is always discouraged. Please see my edit - I now tested this myself. Absolutely unfamiliar with VBA, most of it is simply trial and error.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I'm very new to programming and XML parsing, so I hope you don't mind but can you please explain what **Item(0)** is doing in this line `Title = Author(i).ParentNode.getElementsByTagName("title").Item(0).nodeTypedValue`? Is it pretty much just getting the entire text block within that node starting from the first character (or 0 position)? Also, is there ever a need for using `/text()` within the XPath to the node (it doesn't seem to affect numbers or anything either)? I've been doing this for all my previous work so I feel silly now.. thanks again!! :)